# Getting FreeBusySuggestions in Exchange Server for 15 min meetingDuration

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2016

I am currently working with our HR Dept to update their interview scheduling site. We manage our own Exchange 2016 server that handles the entire company's emails and calendars.

One of the new requirements is to support 15 min interview scheduling. (Previously the shortest option was 30 minutes)

When we calculate available time windows, we start by getting the FreeBusy times from the EWS API on our Exchange server.

```
// Return a set of free/busy times
var freeBusyResults = service.GetUserAvailability(
attendees,
new TimeWindow(request.StartDate, request.EndDate.AddDays(1)),
AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions,
options);

var options = new AvailabilityOptions
{
MeetingDuration = 30, **//NEED THIS TO BE 15**
RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy,
MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0,
MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 48,
GoodSuggestionThreshold = 49,
MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good,
DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(request.StartDate, request.EndDate)
};
```

When testing what returns when the MeetingDuration = 15 I get an error:
*MeetingDuration must be between 30 and 1440*

I am unable to locate a way to change these default values. I was hoping it would as simple as lowering the default min of MeetingDuration, but the only articles I have found reference OWS and online Outlook accounts. These same options do not appear available on an Exchange Server.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

The only online documentation or forum discussions revolve around OWS. I am unable to locate any direction on changing the default min/max values for setting MeetingDuration.

I can schedule a 15 min meeting without issue.

But without more accurate FreeBusy results it will not pick up on available 15 min windows that are available.

The logic of this has been in place for years, and I was only tasked with offering shorter interview intervals, which is not as simple as just changing the MeetingDuration value.